# column of a struct in an array matlab

Tags: matlab

i have a struct with different column, such as "filename", "age" etc...and i want the column "filename" to be put in an array. I tried to do that like follow:

```
for i=1:size(dataSet,2)
   name(i,:) = dataSet(i).filename;
end
```

but i have the following error:

" Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in splitStruct (line 8)

```
name(i,:) = dataSet(i).filename; "
```

I think that i have this error because the character in "dataSet.filename" are of different lenght. For Example: '001A33'
'001A40'
'001A43a'
'001A43b'
'001a02'
'002A03'

How can i solve this problem? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cell array instead:

```
for i=1:size(dataSet,2)
    name{i} = dataSet(i).filename;
end
```

Comment: Even better: `name = {dataSet.filename};`